# ASP.NET Site, EF, Layered Architecture, is my design ok or should I correct it?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, architecture

I have a DAL project, with an entity data model context bound with EF 4.1

I provide methods to access this context through a "Business" project.

My question is the following:

I'm thinking I shouldn't reference the DAL project from somewhere other than the Business project, so my thinking is, I could add "DataContract" interfaces to the Common project I already have, reference this project within the DAL project, extend the partial classes EF has autogenerated for me, inherit the DataContracts corresponding to each of them, and use these DataContracts as the return value of operations in the Business project, thus isolating the DAL project and avoiding to tightly couple it to either the business, or web projects

Is my thinking correct or am I way off?

**Update** In re-reading my own question I find this kind of hard to follow, here's an example of how I'd do it, with one of the entities in the model:

The entity is:

```
namespace Application.Website.Main.Common.DataContracts
{
    public interface IServerApplication
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
        string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        byte MaxAccountsPerUser { get; set; }
        bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This would be in the Application.Website.Main.Common project.

In the DAL project, I would reference the Common project, and extend the partial class of the `ServerApplication` to inherit from that interface, no further changes required.

```
namespace Application.Website.Main.DAL
{
    public partial class ServerApplication : IServerApplication
    {

    }
}
```

In the Business project, I would reference both the DAL and the Common projects, and I'd use these DataContracts as return types:

```
namespace Application.Website.Main.Business.Entities
{
    public class ServerApplication
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IServerApplication> Enabled()
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current.GetDataContext();
            return context.ServerApplications.Where(a => a.Enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, this is the GetDataContext() extension method, placed in the DAL project:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    internal const string _contextDataKey = "dataContext";

    public static EntityDataModelContext GetDataContext(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Items[_contextDataKey] == null)
            httpContext.Items.Add(_contextDataKey, new EntityDataModelContext());

        return (EntityDataModelContext)httpContext.Items[_contextDataKey];
    }
}
```

By the way, where should I be doing the try/catching?
Should that be done on each of the Business-level methods that use the data context?
Or somewhere else?
What would be the best way to handle exceptions at this level?

**Update** I found a hole in my logic. If I wanted for instance to have a method in the Business class for a given entity, it would either have to be static and/or an extension method to the interface. Like this:

```
namespace Application.Website.Main.Business.Entities
{
    public class MembershipUser
    {
        public static int GetRequestCount(this IMembershipUser user)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current.GetDataContext();
            return context.ServerAccountRequests.Count(r => r.MembershipUserId == user.UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, just passing the least information I require for the query:

```
namespace Application.Website.Main.Business.Entities
{
    public class MembershipUser
    {
        public static int GetRequestCount(Guid userId)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current.GetDataContext();
            return context.ServerAccountRequests.Count(r => r.MembershipUserId == userId);
        }
    }
}
```

But how could I make a class so I can just use instance methods, like user.GetRequestCount()? Then the DataContract would need to be a class and not an interface... Or maybe I should have this class to also inherit from the DataContract, but then I would have to implement all of it's members, which I don't intend to do again, since that's already handled by EF at DAL level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking I shouldn't reference the DAL project from somewhere
>   other than the Business project...

Depends how you reference it.  The short answer is even you Business Logic (BL) shouldn't reference the DAL's physical implementation, it should reference an interface that defines the DAL; the concrete impelentation should then be loaded dynamically.

This is on the assumption that the project is beyond trivial in size - you can still write small PoC's, etc, anyway you like.

> I could add "DataContract" interfaces to the Common project I already
>   have

I'd define the data contracts in their own assembly and not in a common project, otherwise everything that references the common "knows" about the data contracts (is that really what you want), and if you have any dependencies in the data contract then everything that references the common will get those extra unwanted dependencies as well.

Although I defining the data contracts should be it a separate assembly, the DTO/POCO objects could be in the common; I've done that before and had good results, because I use these objects to throw data between different layers - not just between the DAL and BL.

Your amin should be to keep all data access & EF references (like SQL) in the concrete DAL implementation.

Comment: What about the BL where I'd want to add Business Logic methods, how could I accomplish that without recurring to "all-static" classes and methods, or duplicating every field name (for a simple insert, for example)

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.